# Static page with url parameters in loopback

Tags: angularjs, node.js, client, loopbackjs, strongloop

I would like a solution for the following problem:

- I have a client in angular running on gulp in this configuration I can navigate throw my page writing in my browser the following:
  (for example) localhost:3000/show/05-05-2017/10
- I have the same client in loopback and it is working with localhost:3000, the problem is when I want to get the same parameter url with loopback localhost:3000/show/05-05-2017/10 I get an error 404 can not get /show/05-05-2017/10

I would like to know some idea where I could find a solution to that or somewhere to look for.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the solution here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/qt9CurkKi_s

Answer (score 1):

Are you running both services on the same port 3000 ? If so that can't work only one server per port is possible.

Change the port of one of them and it should work.

I hope this helps.

Comment: No I am not running the services in the same port. I could find the solution here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/qt9CurkKi_s